# Retrieving machine information from .NET/Mono

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm wondering if is it there any easy, and common between .NET and Mono, way to retrieve machine statistics (eg. free space left, total memory, etc.).
Under the .NET 2.0 profile I was able to identify `DriveInfo` class, but in the previous versions (1.0, 1.1) and Compact framework, which I would like to support, there's nothing like this.
I already excluded the WMI API, since it's not supported by Mono and Compact Framework.

Anyone has ideas about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mono supports the [DriveInfo class](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3ASystem.IO.DriveInfo).  You should be able to get this information the same way in Mono as you do in Microsoft's .NET implementation.

Comment: Yes - but it IS supported on Mono.  On CF, you'll have to P/Invoke.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do most of those things with .NET CF without resorting to P/Invoking Windows Mobile API. So you can strike out cross-platform compatibility with it right away.

As per making this work on .NET 1.1 (I'll pretend you did not mention 1.0...) - why? Do you have any Windows NT 4.0 clients that require this?